# React.js Map Array style for a unique id and each button disabled

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-functional-component

[image: d]

I need **each question button when it is clicked to be disabled**. I would also like to **style each question button**. I already looked for several answers to this problem but I found nothing. As I don't know much about React in this case, should I use useEffect or children.props? If you have any solution please let me know.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-proskuriakova-1o0hf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buttons' state is already available for each button, you just need to use state and disable button.

```
{/* Question buttons */}
{buttons.map((button) => (
  <button key={button.id} disabled={button.clicked} onClick={() => buttonClickHandler(button.id)}>
    {button.label}
  </button>
))}
```

About styling buttons individually, you can create a className for each button and style buttons depending on that:

`<button className={'button-' + button.id}>`

and now from css apply color:

`.button-01 { background: pink; }`

The second approach could be that you create styles for each button inside the state, and consume it from there.

`<button style={button.style}>`

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly here, in relation to the stylization of each button, would you have any options?

Comment: @André here is codesandbox how you style them: https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-leaf-ibknk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks again everything worked perfectly. Could you explain the relationship between css and {`$ {button.clicked? button.isRight: ""} `}

Comment: @André i just noticed your `className` is either `true` or `false`. So based on the `button.clicked` value I set the the `className` to either `button.isRight` if it is clicked and `""` button with no `className` if it isn't clicked.

Comment: @Eugene I think I understand, thank you very much I will study more so that you know how to help someone in the future too :)